# What is the difference between the views of the Sahajiya Vaishnavas and Bauls?

Tags: tantra

There are no doubt similarities between the Sahajiya and Baul, but what are the differences?

Comment: Both Hindus & Muslims can become Bauls but Sahajiyas are always Hindus. Sahajiyas are nominally Gaudiya Vaishanavas but their practices are derived from Vajrayana. These men & women shaved their heads & were notorious for indulging in extra-marital sex on grounds of trying to replicate the divine love between Radha & Krishna. Bauls are exclusively devoted to music as a form of sadhana.